# Sign on several sites

Tags: php, zend-framework, single-sign-on, zend-auth

i have 2 sites (example.com, ex2.com). Fisical is a 1 site with 1 db. When user sing in ex2.com, he was sing in example.com too. How do this?

P.S. Can do this with ZF?

I found a very interesting article on this topic. The author gives some ideas how to implement Multidomain authentication.
http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/09/25/sharing-authentication-over-multiple-sites-single-sign-on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into OpenID? You could lock OpenID consumer "ex2" to allow logins only from your "example.com" OpenID provider.

I am also digging the subject. Some time ago, I already did my own implementation and [got it terribly wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502734/can-you-spot-a-vulnerability-in-my-authentication-protocol).

At the moment I am wondering whether to setup an own OpenID provider and locking consumer sites to accept only it. Another alternative would be yet another own implementation with a [CAS style setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service), where only a hash is passed via the browser, and the user verification is done server-to-server in the background using the hash as a disposable key.

I am not yet sure which one to pick or would some third alternative be better.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look into something like http://cosign.sourceforge.net/. Cosign enables you to create a single point of login for multiple sites. It's not specific to Zend but should work.